# How to format all HttpExceptions as json in symfony5?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, serialization, symfony5

Within a symfony5 controller, I can return json responses via:

```
 return $this->json(['key' => 'content');
```

Yet when I throw an HttpException, I see the default html error page in both dev and production.

I want to create a restful api, so I want to convert all HttpExceptions into json.

I want to configure all my controllers to format their response as json. At most, I want to add one Exception handler that would transform the excpetions into proper messages. (In prod it should have less information, in dev it may contain the exception stacktrace.)

How can I achieve this? I thought I could use the `format` option of the `@Route` annotation but it doesn't work.

This is my example controller:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class StatusController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/status", name="status", format="json")
     * @Template
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function status()
    {
        if (true) {
            // this will render as html, how to serialize it as json?
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("This is an example");
        }


        $ok = new \stdClass();
        $ok->status = "OK";

        return $this->json($ok);
    }
}
```

While looking for this I came across [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/31065) which seems to achieve what I am trying to do, yet I am unsure what I am missing.

On [the symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-errorhandler-component) I found following answer by Yonel Ceruto saying

> you will need to install/enable the serializer component,

yet I have no idea what this entails.

---

In dev and prod I got these html views instead of a json response:

## prod

[image: prod view of html for rendered exceptions]

## dev

[image: dev view of html view for rendered exceptions]

Comment: related: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25905

Comment: [Symfony - How to Customize Error Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

Comment: @CodeSpirit That looks promising, will see if I get to the gist of it.

Comment: @CodeSpirit Feel free to post your answer (you may even copy mine), so I can accept yours. I'd then delete my own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out all I was missing was installing the serializer-pack as pointed out in the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html):

```
composer require symfony/serializer-pack
```

Afterwards, my exceptions render as json fine.

Comment: did you do anything else? The symfony docs do say if you want to change content you need to implement a Normalizer, but even adding that didn't work for me on a fresh install. Do you have any configuration anywhere that tells symfony to use json?

Comment: I needed to send the request with an Accept header. It would be better if I could just configure symfony to only support some formats and default to one.

Comment: @user1718888 You can open a follow up question with your use case, you may reference this question as a link when writing it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a event listener `ExceptionListener`
and register in `services.yml`

```
services:
    ...
    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

##### ExceptionLister.php

```
// src/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();
        // Get incoming request
        $request   = $event->getRequest();

        // Check if it is a rest api request
        if ('application/json' === $request->headers->get('Content-Type'))
        {

            // Customize your response object to display the exception details
            $response = new JsonResponse([
                'message'       => $exception->getMessage(),
                'code'          => $exception->getCode(),
                'traces'        => $exception->getTrace()
            ]);

            // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
            // holds status code and header details
            if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
                $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
                $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
            } else {
                $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }

            // sends the modified response object to the event
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an API development context the simplest and most effective thing is to Override the Default ErrorController. This allows you to format the error output according to the JSON Api standard used in your application ([Jsend](https://github.com/omniti-labs/jsend) on the example)

[See the documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event)

First create your ApiErrorController :

```
php bin/console make:controller --no-template ApiErrorController
```

Second set the framework configuration to use it:

```
framework: 
...

error_controller: App\Controller\ApiErrorController::show
```

Third edit your ApiErrorController :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Throwable;

class ApiErrorController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/api/error', name: 'app_api_error')]
    public function show(Throwable $exception, LoggerInterface $logger): JsonResponse
    {
       
        //Transform Warning status code from 0 to 199 
        $statusCode = (!$exception->getCode() || $exception->getCode()==0)? 199 : $exception->getCode() ;
        
        //Log the error
        if($statusCode<=199){ 
            $logger->warning($exception->getMessage());
        } else {
            $logger->error($exception->getMessage());
        }

        //Prepare basic data output coforming on JSend STD.
        $data = [
            'status'=>($statusCode>=400)? 'error' : 'fail',
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ];

        //If Dev add trace
        if ($this->getParameter('kernel.environment') === 'dev') {
            $data['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
        }

        //return Json
        return $this->json($data, $statusCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `symfony/serializer-pack` not work in my environment.

Finally I create A [ErrorController](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller)
to response json .

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Throwable;

class JsonErrorController
{
    public function show(Throwable $exception, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        return new JsonResponse($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getCode());
    }
}
```