# Symfony5 - Overriding Error output for non-HTML formats

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, symfony5

I try handle all excpetions (Symfony 5) via official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-error-output-for-non-html-formats

I want serialize all exception to JSON format.
I read solution for similar problem in this topic: [How to format all HttpExceptions as json in symfony5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126321/how-to-format-all-httpexceptions-as-json-in-symfony5)
but doesn't resolve my problem.

There my files: src/Controller/ShowController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Component\ShowResponseHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ShowController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/show/{file}", name="show", requirements={"file"=".+"})
     */
    public function index(string $file, string $storageDirectory): Response
    {
        $absolutePath = $storageDirectory.$file;
        if(!file_exists($absolutePath)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Resource not exists");
        }

        return new BinaryFileResponse($absolutePath);

    }
}
```

src/Serializer/ProblemNormalizer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Serializer;

use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class ProblemNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{

    public function normalize($exception, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'exception'=> [
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'code' => $exception->getStatusCode(),
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof FlattenException;
    }
}
```

config/services.yaml

```
services:
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    App\Serializer\ProblemNormalizer:
        tags: ['serializer.normalizer']
```

and of course i have installed package symfony/serializer

```
composer show -i | grep "symfony/serializer"

symfony/serializer                 v5.2.9  Handles serializing and deserializing data structures, including object graphs, into array structures or other formats like XML and JSON
```

What I'm doing wrong or what is not configured?
It always return html output.

**Update**

Console output for:

```
symfony console debug:container | grep normalizer
  Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface                alias for "serializer"                                                                     
  Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer                     alias for "serializer.normalizer.object"                                                   
  Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\PropertyNormalizer                   alias for "serializer.normalizer.property"                                                 
  maker.auto_command.make_serializer_normalizer                                Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Command\MakerCommand                                            
  maker.maker.make_serializer_normalizer                                       Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Maker\MakeSerializerNormalizer                                  
  serializer.denormalizer.array                                                Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer                                  
  serializer.denormalizer.unwrapping                                           Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\UnwrappingDenormalizer                             
  serializer.normalizer.constraint_violation_list                              Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ConstraintViolationListNormalizer                  
  serializer.normalizer.data_uri                                               Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DataUriNormalizer                                  
  serializer.normalizer.dateinterval                                           Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateIntervalNormalizer                             
  serializer.normalizer.datetime                                               Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer                                 
  serializer.normalizer.datetimezone                                           Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeZoneNormalizer                             
  serializer.normalizer.flatten_exception                                      Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\Serialization\Normalizer\FlattenExceptionNormalizer  
  serializer.normalizer.form_error                                             Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\FormErrorNormalizer                                
  serializer.normalizer.json_serializable                                      Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\JsonSerializableNormalizer                         
  serializer.normalizer.mime_message                                           Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\MimeMessageNormalizer                              
  serializer.normalizer.object                                                 Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer                                   
  serializer.normalizer.problem                                                Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ProblemNormalizer                                  
  serializer.normalizer.property                                               Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\PropertyNormalizer                                 
  serializer.normalizer.uid                                                    Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\UidNormalizer                                      

 // To search for a specific service, re-run this command with a search term. (e.g. debug:container log)
```

Comment: Could you check that your normalizer is configured running `symfony console debug:container | grep normalizer`

Comment: @qdequippe Yes. I added output from console in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove App\Serializer\ProblemNormalizer from config/services.yaml. Recheck container for normalizers again `symfony console debug:container | grep normalizer`. Normally you should see your normalizer in the list without any config (Symfony recognizes it by NormalizerInterface). Test with
`curl http://localhost:8000/show/foo.doc -H "Accept: application/json"`

Comment: Thanks!. Reason was.
1. Not needed service: App\Serializer\ProblemNormalizer
2. Second was. I did not send header with accepting response as json: Accept: application/json. Now I have nice response in json format
 {"success":false,"exception":{"message":"Resource not exists","code":404}}

Comment: Consider to use `$context`: e.g. limit response messages, `if($context['debug']) {$message = $exception->getMessage()} else{ $message = $exception->getStatusText()}`, you may also add extra data from original exception or translate your message accordingly based on `$context['exception']`.